# Intellij Error:Cause: org.gradle.internal.component.external.model.DefaultModuleComponentSelector

Tags: java, android, spring, maven, build.gradle

I added maven url to my gradle:

```
repositories {

    mavenCentral()
    maven{
        url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
    }
}
```

and library to spring boot app and I got:

> Error:Cause: org.gradle.internal.component.external.model.DefaultModuleComponentSelector

and library:

> compile 'com.github.jonaslins:fiware-orion-library:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

I use Intellij 2016

Hot to fix it? I added same lib to Android studio and it works

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same issue. It turned out that one of the dependencies could not be resolved from mavencentral. I changed the version and then the build succeeded.

Comment: How did you debug this?

Comment: @KlausGroenbaek Honestly, I don't remember :(

Comment: I had a similar problem, but it looks like various build errors prevented IntelliJ from reloading the gradle configuration and create the .iml files. In my case I had to run `gradlew build` from the command line, to see my build problems and fix them before I could reload the gradle config successfully inside IntelliJ.

Comment: If you run `gradle build` it will show the specific errors.

Comment: Mine was actually a typo in build.gradle, anyways thanks b/c you pointed me in the right direction

Comment: Mine was the wrong username/password.  Running `gradle build` helped me troubleshoot.

Comment: If IntelliJ gradle import fails without any additional infos, check your gradle version. I had a very old gradle 2.x in my project. Upgrading gradle made IntelliJ display which dependency failed.